# [DynamoDB]: Can I share single data model among multiple tables in DynamoDB using DynamoDBMapper?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have more than 1 table which follows the same data modeling structure. Basically, I have a different type of orders and based on its type, I am saving and retrieving orders from the tables based on their type.

**Example :**

- Order Type: A | Table: Order_A
- Order Type: B | Table: Order_B
- Order Type: C | Table: Order_C

All table have same data model.

**Structure:**

OrderID,Date...

I am using DynamoDbMapper. As DynamoDbMapper needs

> @DynamoDBTable(tablename=TABLE)

annotation on class. How can I share this same model among all Order Tables?

```
@DynamoDBTable(tablename=TABLE)    
public class Order{
        public String orderID; 
        public String date;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDBMapper allows you to provide some optional config, including overriding the table name.

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();

// In all cases, setting null tells DynamoDBMapper to use the default value 
DynamoDBMapperConfig mapperConfig = new DynamoDBMapperConfig(
    null, // Save behavior
    null, //ConsistentReads
    “TableName”, //TableNameOverride
    null // PaginationLoadingStrategy
);

DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client, mapperConfig, cp);
```

You can also provide a DynamoDBMapperConfig on a per-operation basis.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptionalConfig.html

Comment: Thank You @matthew-pope. I found the solution and I followed the same solution.